# validates_length_of :number doesn't count 0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to validate the length of a number entered into a form. In my model the validation looks like the following:

```
validates_length_of :number, in: 4..10, too_long: 'Not a valid ID number too long', too_short: 'Not a valid ID number too short'
```

When I try to use the number in irb console

```
sample.number = "0000030"
```

I get the following error:

```
:number=>["Not a valid ID number too short"]}>
```

What is the best way to validate the length of a number that includes zero?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work fine when I use it given that number is a string and not an integer.

Comment: if it is going to be saved as an integer, I think it will remove the '000' and will just save 30. So might as well change the datatype to string.